# Equivalent of "expandedHintEnabled" in Jetpack Compose TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-textinputlayout, android-compose-textfield

Is there any way to put OutlinedTextField's label on top (expanded) and still have the placeholder, when OutlinedTextField is not in focus?

In xml layouts we have TextInputLayout that has **expandedHintEnabled** attribute that does the expanding.

[image]

Comment: Not currently. The `placeholder` applies an `alpha`  modifier with this condition: `InputPhase.UnfocusedEmpty -> if (showLabel) 0f else 1f`.

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `placeholder` applies an `alpha` modifier with this condition `InputPhase.UnfocusedEmpty -> if (showLabel) 0f else 1f` and there isn't a parameter to achieve the same behaviour of `expandedHintEnabled`.

A workaround can be to use a `visualTransformation` to display a placeholder when the text is empty, removing the `placeholder` parameter.

Something like:

```
    val textColor = if (text.isEmpty())
        MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(ContentAlpha.medium)
    else
        LocalContentColor.current.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current)

    val textStyle = if (text.isEmpty())
        LocalTextStyle.current.merge(MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1)
    else
        LocalTextStyle.current

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        //placeholder = { Text("Placeholder") },
        label = { Text("Label") },
        visualTransformation = if (text.isEmpty())
            PlaceholderTransformation("Placeholder")
        else VisualTransformation.None,
        textStyle = textStyle,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            textColor = textColor
        )
    )
```

[image]

with:

```
class PlaceholderTransformation(val placeholder: String) : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return PlaceholderFilter(text, placeholder)
    }
}

fun PlaceholderFilter(text: AnnotatedString, placeholder: String): TransformedText {

    val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            return 0
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            return 0
        }
    }

    return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(placeholder), numberOffsetTranslator)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. What about if we want to put label always on top, without focus? (no placeholder)